# challenging special numpy operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array that is full of indices of numbers `input`. I want to check if certain indices `indices` are in it. Say that the i'th row of `input`, `input[i]` has entries `j_1<...<j_n` that their values belong to `indices`. I would like to switch the value of `input[i,j_n]` with a random value from `indices`. How can I do it elegantly and efficiently?

Example:

input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

indices = [2,4,6]

input --> [[1,4,3],[4,5,4],[7,8,9]]

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, do you just want to replace all values in `input` that are also present in `indices` with another (potentially the same) random value from `indices`?

Comment: Should the random value always be the same (as in your example output)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```py
import random

input = [[i if i not in indices else random.choice(indices) for i in x] for x in input]
```

Better, of course, to check in `set` instead of `list`:

```py
import random

d = {*indices}
input = [[i if i not in d else random.choice(indices) for i in x] for x in input]
```

Comment: But this also changes a j_i < j_n. So it won't cut it.

Comment: I don't quite underdand what's your indexes `j_i`and `j_n`. But I think you could achieve this using `enumerate` in `for j, x in enumerate(input)` and adding check in `if`, like `if i < j and i not in d else`...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want something like this:

```
input = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]])

indices = [2, 4, 6]

mask = np.isin(input, indices)
# array([[False,  True, False],
#        [ True, False,  True],
#        [False, False, False]])

input[mask] = np.random.choice(indices, np.count_nonzero(mask))
# array([[1, 6, 3],
#        [6, 5, 4],
#        [7, 8, 9]])
```